# Is it possible to send KNative events using any kind of SDK in java/kotlin without relying on Http?

Tags: kotlin, kubernetes, quarkus, knative

So I'm using quarkus and funqy to listen to knative events and it works like a charm.
The way I used to test it locally with minikube/kind can be followed in the steps below.

- Created a `kubernetes service` containing the quarkus image that has the @funq annotation
- Created a `kubernetes trigger` that will invoke the service when receive the "myOwnEvent" event
- Create a `kubernetes namespace`(knativetutorial) so I can put everything togueter
- Create a `kubernetes broker` for this namespace (named default)
- Create a `kubernetes pod` just so I can get inside it to make curl requests to the broker

After my local setup is done I made a curl request from inside the `kubernetes pod` that I created.
The curl was something like that:

```shell

```
curl -v "http://broker-ingress.knative-eventing.svc.cluster.local/knativetutorial/default" -X POST -H "Ce-Id: 1234" -H "Ce-Specversion: 1.0" -H "Ce-Type: myOwnEvent" -H "Ce-Source: curl" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '"Start"'
```

```

And it worked I successfully was able to manually trigger an event that was received by my quarkus application.

Now my main goal is to create a new event in my application and not manually.

I found some solutions on the internet, but they are all using an http POST request to the broker from inside the application (basically what I did but in the code itself).

I try https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client but I also couldn't find a way to send/publish an event.

Is there any other solution or should I rely on http for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knative Uses [CloudEvents](https://cloudevents.io/) for message routing; in particular, [CloudEvents over HTTP](https://github.com/cloudevents/spec/blob/v1.0.2/cloudevents/bindings/http-protocol-binding.md), as described in [the Knative Eventing spec](https://github.com/knative/specs/blob/main/specs/eventing/data-plane.md#http-verbs).  If you're looking for a higher-level library, you can use the [CloudEvents Java SDK](https://github.com/cloudevents/sdk-java), but it will still be HTTP underneath.

Part of the goal of Knative Eventing is to work well with a large variety of programming languages without needing a specal-purpose SDK, so just using HTTP to post events is actually a design feature compared with implementing something like AMQP for sending.

Comment: You can use the "accept" answer option to mark this as the canonical answer for future people who are searching.

Comment: Sorry I forgot.
Done